# How to disable warning that occurred by overriding in Ranorex (c#)

Tags: c#, overriding, ranorex

I try to use overriding in Ranorex Studio (c# language using)

```
public class DropListActions
{
     public void SimpleSelectByInnerText(string text, bool close){
     }
}
public class CheckBoxDropListWithInputField : DropListActions
{
     //overriding
     public void SimpleSelectByInnerText(string text, bool close){
     }
}
```

all works well, but in the report showed warnings:

> '****************.CheckBoxDropListWithInputField.SimpleSelectByInnerText(string,
>   bool)' hides inherited member
>   '****************.DropListActions.SimpleSelectByInnerText(string,
>   bool)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. (CS0108) -
>   C:\*****\\Ranorex\RanorexStudio
>   Projects\*****\DropListActions.cs:117,18

For example in `java` all overriding methods marked by `@Override` annotation. Maybe in `c#` there exists an appropriate way to do this? How to skip those warnings messages?

Comment: In C# everything is non-virtual by default, unlike in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the base class and the derived class have a method with the same name (`SimpleSelectByInnerText`).  The compiler is telling you that the method in the derived class is "hiding" the method in the base class (you're not overriding it because only `virtual` or `abstract` methods can be overridden).

To get rid of this warning you can use the `new` keyword which tells the compiler that you intend to "hide" the base method:

```
public class CheckBoxDropListWithInputField : DropListActions
{
     public new void SimpleSelectByInnerText(string text, bool close)
     {   //  ^ new keyword here before the return type   
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `override` and mark the method in the base class as `virtual`:

```
public class DropListActions
{
     public virtual void SimpleSelectByInnerText(string text, bool close)
     {
     }
}

public class CheckBoxDropListWithInputField : DropListActions
{
     public override void SimpleSelectByInnerText(string text, bool close)
     {
     }
}
```

See [What’s the difference between override and new?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/whats-the-difference-between-override-and-new/) by Jon Skeet and  [Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108) for more info.